# Search result is not loaded if the UFT is opened

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have an TIBCOCIM application .

**What happen when i open Webpage alone  and not with the UFT**

On hitting  the search button ,i get the list of records matching my search criteria .

**When i open the UFT and Then the application,**
On hitting  search button using UFT scripts, I didn't get the list of records matching my search criteria. I get Done with the error icon in the IE status bar. When i click the error icon. It gives me message Object doesn't support this property in the app.jss

Answer (score 0):

Screen shots would be helpful to answer you question

Comment: Naptser , i would like to .But it is a secured one .So unable print screen shot .When i check with the develper tools .it is an ajax script

Comment: did the UFT scripts run successfully? if not, what error did UFT throw ?